# Blank Screen On Boot on Dual Booting Two Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I have a Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 on a partition which I am not allowed upgrading (for reasons out of my control) so I decided to install fresh Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 (5.19.0-35-generic #36~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC) on a separate partition of the same disk (which had previously been used as the swap partition for the initial Ubuntu). The original Ubuntu installation did NOT have a efi partion so I assume it is in legacy bios mode but during the new installation, I added a UEFI partition and created a new partition for the Ubuntu root using the remaining free space. So I think the new Ubuntu is booting with UEFI and the orignal one boots with legacy boot. I have three partitions on this disk, on for the original ubuntu, one efi and one the new ubuntu.

The installation was successful, but now, when I start the computer, I am greeted with a blank screen and NOT even the bios splash screen (picture below), and after about 30 seconds, it boots into the new Ubuntu without even displaying the GRUB interface.

My guess is that grub screen is there as I can guess when the grub is on and switch to the old ubuntu blindly by pressing the right keyboard keys but the graphic cards are not displaying them, even though I have updated the drivers for them. I believe fast boot is enabled, I can not disable it without getting into the bios setting. The following command does NOT help either. The computer reboot and just display a blank screen forever. My guess is that bios screen is loaded but not shown.

`sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup`

Also, I am unable to boot with the USB key anymore as it just boots into the new ubuntu.

Why would this even happen to the extent that can NOT even see the boot splash screen (picture below)?  Can someone please help me resolve this issue without removing the hard drive?

[image]

Comment: I can’t answer the specifics - but (& apologies if this is a bit irritating!) - I think you should be thinking more of not being able to risk *not* updating 16.04; also, entering the bios settings should be before the os has been read - are you certain you’re pressing the correct key?

Comment: You've not been very specific with details; you mention Ubuntu 22.04 but not if you're talking about Ubuntu Desktop (thus `ubiquity` installer), Ubuntu Server (thus `subiquity`) or *flavor*).  By default `ubiquity` will automatically add an ESP on new installs; but that is optional! & the system will boot with/without it (*though ESP is required if you're using EFI/Secure-uEFI to boot*).  Your question leaves me things in doubt; you don't specifically mention what mode 16.04 was installed in, what mode windows was installed in, nor which 22.04 system nor what mode it was installed in..

Comment: If windows fastboot was disabled, no windows hibernate function was used (ie. clean file-system) & all your OSes were installed in the same mode (legacy/uEFI primarily!) - I'd expect a normal boot if your machine is capable of running the 22.04 ISO & kernel stack you installed (*you didn't specify which 22.04 product nor which ISO thus we can't know*)

Comment: @guiverc sure, sorry I should have been clear. I will update the question. but I am talking about Ubuntu desktop. and there is no Windows involved here. just two different Ubuntu desktops on two different partitions of same disk. Because I found no efi partition for the Ubuntu 16.04, I assume that one was installed with legacy bios mode so I am in a situation that one OS is in legacy bios and the second (22.04) one in UEFI mode. I did not enable any fastboot but somehow I think it got enabled. The exact 22.04 details are 5.19.0-35-generic #36~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC

Comment: @Will I understand but from power on, screen is fully blank until the new ubuntu fully boots and show the login screen

Comment: Have you tried holding down Del or f2 immediately after turning on (ie keep the key held down)?

Comment: @Will. for sure